# Downcasting in Java ? Is this a downcasting issue at all?

Tags: java, downcast

So I have a POJO class let´s call it: InnerDomainObject.
Then I have an object representing this object, with a few more fields, for communication towards different clients (it s an API DTO): OuterDomainObject

Because the DTO has in fact all of the POJOs fields, I made OuterDomainObject inherit from InnerDomainObject.

Now I need to somehow cast InnerDomainObject to OuterDomainObject --> not possible.

I want to avoid writing a constructor iterating through all the fields. 
I want to avoid writing useless code.

I just want OuterDomainObject to be created out of InnerDomainOBject´s values and then add some to it before sending it to the client.

What´s the best way of doing this ?

Comment: One way is to use composition rather than inheritance.

Comment: Unfortunately not, JB Nizet. It is crucial for me to add additional attributes within the same levle of hierarchy. A composition would introduce an additional level of hierarchy inside the composed object: like: outerDTO.innerDTO.innerattribute and outerDTO.outerattributes - I need all the attributes flat

Comment: In the DTO, or in the JSON (assuming the DTO is transformed to JSON)? If you want inheritance, then you'll have to copy.

Comment: Ok. Another way would be to code a utility transforming the parent to the child for those cases by using reflections. Or is there something like that out there already ? I d guess so

Comment: There are several bean mappers doing that sort of thing, but it makes the code slow, harder to understand and use, and only saves a few keystrokes.

Answer (score 0):

You sound like you are using the [Adapter Pattern](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern). You shouldn't need to cast an InnerDomainObject to an OuterDomainObject. You should use composition: the OuterDomainObject should hold a reference to an InnerDomainObject, which will likely be passed into a constructor. When a client invokes a method on an OuterDomainObject, if that method exists in InnerDomainObject, the OuterDomainObject should call that method on its instance of InnerDomainObject. Instead of casting an InnerDomainObject `foo` to an OuterDomainObject, just create a new OuterDomainObject and pass in `foo`: `new OuterDomainObject(foo)`. You will need to write some simple glue code, but the result is very clean.

Comment: Mh. What would the OuterDomainObject look like then ? Like: holding the innerdomainobject ? Would the innerdomainobject be an attribute of it ?

Comment: Yes, the OuterDomainObject would hold a reference to an InnerDomainObject, which would be set in OuterDomainObject's constructor.

Comment: Well Daniel, that was what first came to mind. But for "reasons" (this whole "problem" is actually only there because I m in a transition to unify/generify all objects in the API) I wanted it to be flat. Therefore inheritance. Anyhow, thanks for your answer - it seems it cannot be done and it seems I ll have to live with this until the API has made its transition.